# Is it possible to call a fragment from within a fragment thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a fragment for the head tag, and from within this I would like to call another fragment for my styles and scripts.

templates/fragments/commonHead.html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment="commonHead(title)">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <div th:replace="~{fragments/styles :: styles}"></div>
    <div th:replace="~{fragments/scripts :: scripts}"></div>
    <title th:text="${title}"></title>
</head>
```

templates/fragments/styles.html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">    
<div th:fragment="styles" th:remove="tag">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/normalize.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</div>
```

templates/fragments/scripts.html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<div th:fragment="scripts" th:remove="tag">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@1.1.3/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</div>
```

And this is how I am calling the common head fragment.

templates/schedule.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="~{fragments/commonHead :: commonHead('Schedule')}"></head>
<body>
----
```

But when I do this, there are no errors, but the generated html does not complete the head tag. There must be some issue, but I have no indication what is wrong. Is it not possible to do this? I have tried both with `<div th:replace="~{fragments/styles :: styles}"></div>` and `<div th:replace="~{styles :: styles}"></div>` (same for scripts) in case it doesn't need the directory when the fragment is in the same folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<body>
```

EDIT:
After further troubleshooting here, it seems like it is completely overlooking the fragments in commonHead. If I intentionally call something with the wrong name (like `<div th:replace="~{fragmentsX/stylesX :: stylesX}"></div>`) I get no errors, and of course the fragment is not included.

Comment: Looks like some typos in your file and fragment names. (a) You have a file called `scripts.html` - but you refer to it as `styles`, as in `fragments/styles`. (b) You have a section in your fragment file called `scripts`, as in `th:fragment="scripts"` - but you refer to it as `styles`, as in `:: styles`. I would expect to see `th:replace="~{fragments/scripts :: scripts}"`, based on that. But this is not an answer because you also said `there are no errors` - and I would expect there to be errors thrown by Java due to failed Thymeleaf rendering...

Comment: Otherwise, yes it is absolutely possible to call a fragment from a fragment.

Comment: Sorry for the typos. I have this for both scripts and styles, and but I only included the scripts for simplicity in the example.

Comment: Thank you for the edits. Your code is still referring to `styles.html`. That file is not shown in the question. That file is either (a) missing - and therefore causing an error (not shown in the question). Or (b) it exists - but it is not relevant to the problem. Take a look at [mre]. We should be able to copy/paste your code and run it, without needing to edit it ourselves, to recreate your problem.

Comment: When I take your code and edit it (making some guesses as to how you are _actually_ using it), I cannot recreate your problem. My fragments work as expected.

Comment: I apologize. I attempted to simplify things by only including the fragment for scripts, (because I used the exact same setup for styles, and both had the issue), but it appears that added more confusion. I have added the fragment for styles also.

Comment: No problem - I appreciate your edits. Unfortunately, I cannot recreate your problem. I get the correct/expected result. Maybe someone else will see the issue!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue was with having the `head` tag in my commonHead fragment. When I changed that to `div` (with th:remove="tag" so that the div didn't show up in the html), then it worked fine.

Only change was made to templates/fragments/commonHead.html, final version is below.

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <div th:fragment="commonHead(title)" th:remove="tag">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <div th:replace="~{fragments/styles :: styles}"></div>
    <div th:replace="~{fragments/scripts :: scripts}"></div>
    <title th:text="${title}"></title>
</div>
```